# Subquery returns more than 1 row in like %..%

Tags: mysql, sql

i am working with bank transaction table witch contain 67000 transactions for around 800 customer from January to October so what i want is to calculate number of transactions for each customer per month i want the final result will be like cust_id , number of transaction for jan ,number of transaction for Feb ... til October i tryed this query

```
 SELECT 
    cut_id,
    CASE WHEN tra_date LIKE '%Oct%' 
        THEN 
            (select count(tra_date) from tab where tra_date like '%Oct%' GROUP by cut_id)
        ELSE 0 
    END AS oct,
    CASE WHEN tra_date LIKE '%Sep%' 
        THEN 
            (select count(tra_date) from tab where tra_date like '%Sep%' GROUP by cut_id)
        ELSE 0 
    END AS sept 
    FROM tab 
    GROUP by cut_id
```

but i found this error    #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Try cleaning up the question a bit so it is readable.

Comment: Why are your dates stored as strings? That's a **huge** mistake in the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have a *sane* schema that uses actual an actual datetime type for your transaction dates, rather than the apparent *insane* schema in the question that uses strings. Given that, your query would look like this:

```
SELECT 
    cut_id, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN month(tra_date) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Oct,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month(tra_date) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sept
FROM tab 
GROUP by cut_id
```

Comment: iamnot flow sane schema how can i do it?

Comment: Well, the best option is to fix the broken schema. Otherwise, just replace the `month(tra_date) = n` expression with something that does correctly select for the records you want.

Answer (score 0):

In this section

```
 (select count(tra_date) from tab where tra_date like '%Oct%' GROUP by cut_id)
```

When you do a `count` with a `group by`, and there are multiple values for the thing you are grouping by, you get multiple values. Based on your requirements, you need to choose which single value you want.

Maybe you need to do this instead

```
 (select count(tra_date) from tab t1 where t1.tra_date like '%Oct%' and t1.cut_id = tab.cut_id)
```